# Get User Name on Action Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, action-filter

I use MVC4 web application with Web API. I want to create an action filter, and I want to know which user (a logged-in user) made the action. How can I do it?

```
public class ModelActionLog : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(SHttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
       string username = ??
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
       ??
    }
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can try

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
           string username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        }
```

Check for authenticated user first:

```
string userName = null;
if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Try to use

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Hope it works for you

Comment: I use WebAPI (System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute), your solution doesn't work

Comment: if u r using `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute` then just use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` for getting User Name on `Action Filter`..see my updated answer,and try atleast once.

Comment: Please do not suggest to use HttpContext.Current in WebApi. WebApi is async and in case two request come together, you can mix two request data together. It migth seem to work, but it is definitly not thread safe

Comment: According to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24973147/90033 if everything is correctly configured and running on/configure for .net 4.5 it should work

Comment: It is not Testable because of static HttpContext property. Please use actionContext.RequestContext instead.

Answer (score 66):

Bit late for an answer but this is best solution if you are using HttpActionContext in your filter You can always use it as mentioned here:-

```
public override Task OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   if (actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   {
      var userName = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name;
   }
}
```

Comment: System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext does not have RequestContext.

Comment: it is in System.Net.Http and the guy who has asked this questioned mentioned in one of his comment that he is using Web API

Comment: You need to have the nuget package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` installed in order to see the `RequestContext` property

Comment: This answer is why you should always look beyond the accepted answer. +1

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps not the prettiest solution, but for Web API ActionFilter you can do the following:

```
var controller = (actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller as ApiController);
var principal = controller.User;
```

Of course, this only applies if your controllers actually inherit from ApiController.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need

```
string username = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: I get a message - 'System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext' does not contain a definition for 'HttpContext' and no extension method 'HttpContext' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I use System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute

Answer (score 0):

```
 HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```