# Startup Class IsInRole .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm working inside of ConfigureServices of my Startup class. I want to run IsInRole() which I understand to be this method in order to populate an Action:

However, running:

```
System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal.IsInRole("BRV_Projects_Edit");
```

Is clearly not successful as this refers to an interface, not an instance implementing that interface?

My Question is, within the context of ConfigureService, where I am defining a custom attribute how can I access (inject?) the Principal of the current user.

Comment: no you can't because startup code runs before it starts listening for web requests and there isn't any httpcontext yet

Comment: HttpContext.User aka claimsprincipal of the current user does not exist until after the authentication middleware runs.

Comment: any way to get HttpContext into an ActionFilterAttribute?

Comment: this may answer it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649551/get-user-name-on-action-filter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get User Name on Action Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649551/get-user-name-on-action-filter)

Comment: Thanks looking at it now, looks like there are some differences MVC4 vs .net core

Comment: It is all different in aspnet core. Take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.2 Seems like `[Authorize(Role="xxx")]` would be what you need

Answer (score 0):

Per the feedback above User.InRole is not accessible at this point in the pipeline but is accessible via the creation of an ActionFilterAttribute.

The ActionFilterAttribute makes available OnActionExecuting, [Get User Name on Action Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649551/get-user-name-on-action-filter) extremely similar to this post except with changes relevant to .net core

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Controller is Controller controller)
        {
            controller.ViewBag.CanEdit = filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("group1");
```